# left join not working correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

I am left joining message replies, on to the main message, but when I left join the user table is not being joined:

```
"SELECT messages.*, 
       message_replies.message_reply_message AS message_body 
FROM   messages 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON messages.message_user = users.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN message_replies 
              ON messages.message_id = message_replies.message_reply_main 
       LEFT JOIN user_personal_information 
              ON messages.message_user = 
                 user_personal_information.user_personal_information_user" .                   
                 $user . " " . $order . ""
```

When I remove:

```
messages.*, 
   message_replies.message_reply_message AS message_body
```

and just select `*` then it works fine, but they my message replies aren't included, here's my php:

```
$messages = MessageModel::messages($user," WHERE message_user=? "," AND message_deleted=0 AND message_permdeleted=0   ORDER BY message_date DESC LIMIT 5");
```

and my message sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_subject` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `message_body` text NOT NULL,
  `message_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_read` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `message_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `message_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `message_permdeleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `message_type` varchar(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `messages` (`message_id`, `message_user`, `message_subject`, `message_body`, `message_to`, `message_read`, `message_date`, `message_deleted`, `message_permdeleted`, `message_type`) VALUES
(1, 3, 'test', 'hello', 12, 1, '2015-10-12 02:09:51', 0, 0, 'sent'),
```

and my message replies:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message_replies` (
  `message_reply_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_reply_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_reply_main` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_reply_message` text NOT NULL,
  `message_reply_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `message_replies` (`message_reply_id`, `message_reply_user`, `message_reply_main`, `message_reply_message`, `message_reply_date`) VALUES
(1, 3, 1, 'Hello, this is just a test reply\r\n', '2015-09-29 18:42:23'),
```

user sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_enabled` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user_staff` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_account_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_registerdate` date NOT NULL,
  `user_twofactor` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_twofackey` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_forgot_email_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_emailverified` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unverified',
  `user_banned` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unbanned',
  `user_has_avatar` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_has_banner` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `user_username`, `user_email`, `user_password`, `user_enabled`, `user_staff`, `user_account_type`, `user_registerdate`, `user_twofactor`, `user_twofackey`, `user_forgot_email_code`, `user_emailverified`, `user_banned`, `user_has_avatar`, `user_has_banner`) VALUES
(3, 'lol', 'email@mail.com', '$2y$10$jjTLGiOC2XtwhzRrLOq15euw4S0jXmWveEctd9pYEL44LEt3Vdfa2', 1, 'admin', 'Business', '2015-07-21', 0, '5GILYNBWBXVAUV3A', 'd71a30cb75faed7c48cba971cf934922', 'unverified', 'unbanned', 1, 1),
```

So how can I get my sql to work with the information supplied above

Var_dump:

> array(5) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (10) { ["message_id"]=> string(2)
>   "10" ["message_user"]=> string(1) "3" ["message_subject"]=> string(8)
>   "yooooooo" ["message_body"]=> string(5) "fffff" ["message_to"]=>
>   string(2) "12" ["message_read"]=> string(1) "1" ["message_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2015-10-12 03:36:32" ["message_deleted"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["message_permdeleted"]=> string(1) "0" ["message_type"]=> string(8)
>   "recieved" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#23 (10) { ["message_id"]=>
>   string(2) "10" ["message_user"]=> string(1) "3" ["message_subject"]=>
>   string(8) "yooooooo" ["message_body"]=> string(3) "lol"
>   ["message_to"]=> string(2) "12" ["message_read"]=> string(1) "1"
>   ["message_date"]=> string(19) "2015-10-12 03:36:32"
>   ["message_deleted"]=> string(1) "0" ["message_permdeleted"]=>
>   string(1) "0" ["message_type"]=> string(8) "recieved" } [2]=>
>   object(stdClass)#24 (10) { ["message_id"]=> string(1) "9"
>   ["message_user"]=> string(1) "3" ["message_subject"]=> string(8)
>   "jhjhjhjh" ["message_body"]=> NULL ["message_to"]=> string(2) "12"
>   ["message_read"]=> string(1) "1" ["message_date"]=> string(19)
>   "2015-10-12 03:34:54" ["message_deleted"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["message_permdeleted"]=> string(1) "0" ["message_type"]=> string(4)
>   "sent" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#25 (10) { ["message_id"]=> string(1)
>   "8" ["message_user"]=> string(1) "3" ["message_subject"]=> string(8)
>   "jhjhjhjh" ["message_body"]=> NULL ["message_to"]=> string(2) "12"
>   ["message_read"]=> string(1) "0" ["message_date"]=> string(19)
>   "2015-10-12 03:34:40" ["message_deleted"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["message_permdeleted"]=> string(1) "0" ["message_type"]=> string(4)
>   "sent" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#26 (10) { ["message_id"]=> string(1)
>   "7" ["message_user"]=> string(1) "3" ["message_subject"]=> string(2)
>   "yo" ["message_body"]=> NULL ["message_to"]=> string(2) "12"
>   ["message_read"]=> string(1) "0" ["message_date"]=> string(19)
>   "2015-10-12 03:33:17" ["message_deleted"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["message_permdeleted"]=> string(1) "0" ["message_type"]=> string(4)
>   "sent" } }

```
user_personal_information

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_personal_information` (
  `user_personal_information_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_personal_information_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_firstname` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `user_surname` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `user_birthdate` date NOT NULL,
  `user_age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_gender` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `user_contactemail` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `user_telephone` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `user_mobile` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `user_introduction` text NOT NULL,
  `user_occupation` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `user_relocate` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `user_available` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `user_fax` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_street` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_zip` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_state` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_country` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `user_personal_information_chestsize` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_personal_information_waistsize` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_personal_information_bootsize` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_personal_information_harness_size` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_personal_information_inside_leg` varchar(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user_personal_information`
--

INSERT INTO `user_personal_information` (`user_personal_information_id`, `user_personal_information_user`, `user_firstname`, `user_surname`, `user_birthdate`, `user_age`, `user_gender`, `user_contactemail`, `user_telephone`, `user_mobile`, `user_introduction`, `user_occupation`, `user_relocate`, `user_available`, `user_fax`, `user_street`, `user_zip`, `user_city`, `user_state`, `user_country`, `user_personal_information_chestsize`, `user_personal_information_waistsize`, `user_personal_information_bootsize`, `user_personal_information_harness_size`, `user_personal_information_inside_leg`) VALUES
(1, 3, 'name', '123', '0000-00-00', 0, '', '', '07000', '00000', 'hello\r\n', 'Looking for work', '', '', '', '  jfkfkfjk', 'kjkjkjkj', 'kjkjkjk', 'kjkjk', 'United Kingdom', '123', '0', '0', '0', '0'),
```

Comment: Have you tried using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` ?

Comment: Yeah and still not selecting the user's table.

Comment: @bot: May you let me know if there is any difference in left join and left outer join in MYSQL. As my assumption is that there is no left outer join in mysql.

Comment: yah right. i was carried out as im always using mssql. lol thanks.

Comment: @randommman: May you share the basis on which you are saying that user table is not joining to check the issue.

Comment: There's almost no point LEFT JOINing a table from which you select no columns (with one important exception)

Comment: @zafar malik your assumption is mistaken

Comment: @Strawberry: I agree your remarks that "There's almost no point LEFT JOINing a table from which you select no columns"...further I will be very thankful if you help to understand the difference between left join and left outer join in mysql as I could not get any document regarding left outer join in mysql documentation.

Comment: @ZafarMalik In a nutshell, MySQL supports two kinds of JOIN, `INNER JOIN` and `OUTER JOIN`. There are two kinds of `OUTER JOIN`: `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. Theoretically, for every `LEFT OUTER JOIN` there is a functionally equivalent `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, but because the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` formulation is generally held to be more intuitive, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` is almost never used. Finally, both the `INNER` and `OUTER` keywords are optional, and so frequently disregarded. All of this is covered in the manual.

Comment: @Strawberry: Same I was saying that there is no difference in left join and left outer join as bot asked randommman to change left join with left outer join.

Comment: @ZafarMalik Well, OK, but that's not what you said.

Comment: @Strawberry: First of all sorry as you answered only just on my remarks that "my assumption is that there is no left outer join in mysql" while I mean to say in earlier sentence "if there is any difference in left join and left outer join in MYSQL" that both are same. Well thanks to correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Table alias for messages table and try :

```
SELECT ms.*, 
       ms_r.message_reply_message AS message_body 
FROM   messages AS ms
       LEFT JOIN users AS u
              ON ms.message_user = u.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN message_replies AS ms_r
              ON ms.message_id = ms_r.message_reply_main 
       LEFT JOIN user_personal_information AS u_p_i
              ON ms.message_user = u_p_i.user_personal_information_user
       WHERE ms.message_user=3 AND ms.message_deleted=0 AND ms.message_permdeleted=0 
       ORDER BY ms.message_date DESC LIMIT 5
```

[SEE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e360/2) live example

Comment: Tried still not selecting the users table :(

Comment: added data to my original post.

Comment: Thanks and value of $user and $order variables

Comment: WHERE ms.message_user=3 AND ms.message_deleted=0 AND ms.message_permdeleted=0   ORDER BY ms.message_date DESC LIMIT 5

You can remove user and order and add the sql above which is user an d order, it may be easier that way.

Comment: Friend user_personal_information table is missing could you send me structure and row data of this table please

Comment: added to my original post.

Comment: I re prepare  Join query with 3 table given in original post and its working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bfb7/3/0  live code

Comment: I have updated the code and its working fine... Please check on sqlfiddle for live example :  url : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e360/2

Comment: Did you check on query on sqlfiddle  I use all 4 table and make a query. Please ask me if have any question...

Comment: there's no user personal informaion on that though, is there?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Put users first in left join

```
"SELECT messages.*, 
       message_replies.message_reply_message AS message_body 
FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN messages 
              ON messages.message_user = users.user_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN message_replies 
              ON messages.message_id = message_replies.message_reply_main 
       LEFT JOIN user_personal_information 
              ON messages.message_user = 
                 user_personal_information.user_personal_information_user" .                   
                 $user . " " . $order . ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
SELECT ms.*, 
       msr.message_reply_message AS message_body 
FROM   
(select * from messages )ms 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON ms.message_user = users.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN message_replies  msr
              ON ms.message_id = msr.message_reply_main 
       LEFT JOIN user_personal_information  usrp
              ON ms.message_user = 
                 usrp.user_personal_information_user
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your mysql statement is that you have 2 columns with the same name.

```
"SELECT messages.*, 
message_replies.message_reply_message AS message_body

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
`message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`message_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`message_subject` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`message_body` text NOT NULL,
```

The `messages` table already had the column `message_body` and you tried to get another column and assigning it AS `message_body` again.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When I tried to create table `message_replies`, I got an error in `current_timestamp`, so I changed the datetime datatype to timestamp and tried the query.

As per the data in your tables and the `SELECT` query, I think got the correct result.

```
SELECT messages.*, 
       message_replies.message_reply_message AS message_body 
FROM   messages 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON messages.message_user = users.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN message_replies 
              ON messages.message_id = message_replies.message_reply_main 
       LEFT JOIN user_personal_information 
              ON messages.message_user = 
                 user_personal_information.user_personal_information_user
        WHERE message_user=3 AND message_deleted=0 AND message_permdeleted=0   ORDER BY message_date DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT `messages`.*,`message_replies`.`message_reply_message` AS `message_body`
FROM
`new_trail_new`.`messages`
INNER JOIN `new_trail_new`.`message_replies` 
    ON (`messages`.`message_id` = `message_replies`.`message_reply_main`)
INNER JOIN `new_trail_new`.`user_personal_information` 
    ON (`messages`.`message_user` = `user_personal_information`.`user_personal_information_user`)
INNER JOIN `new_trail_new`.`users` 
    ON (`messages`.`message_user` = `users`.`user_id`)
WHERE `messages`.`message_user`=3 AND `messages`.`message_deleted`=0 AND `messages`.`message_permdeleted`=0 
   ORDER BY `messages`.`message_date` DESC LIMIT 5;
```

This is the ouptput i got by executing the above query:

```
message_id  message_user  message_subject  message_body  message_to  
----------  ------------  ---------------  ------------  ---------- 
1             3         test             hello          12  

message_read  message_date        message_deleted message_permdeleted  
------------  ------------------- ---------------  ------------------- 
1       2015-10-12 02:09:51              0                  0 

message_type       message_body
-----------------  ----------------------------                  
sent               Hello, this is just a test reply
```

Comment: It should also select the message_user's personal_information which is what it's not doing